# sql SUM: change null with 0

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT bgdepartemen.c_kodedept AS c_kodedept,
       bgdepartemen.vc_namadept AS vc_namadept,
       bgdivisi.c_kodediv AS c_kodediv,
       bgdivisi.vc_namadiv AS vc_namadiv,
       bggroup0.c_kodegrp0 AS c_kodegrp0,
       bggroup0.vc_namagrp0 AS vc_namagrp0,
       (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(bgbudget0.n_nilai))
        FROM (bgbudget0 JOIN bggroup1 ON bgbudget0.c_kodegrp1 = bggroup1.c_kodegrp1)
        WHERE bgbudget0.n_tahun = 2016 AND
              bgbudget0.n_bulan >= 2 AND
              bgbudget0.n_bulan <= 3 AND
              bgbudget0.c_kodediv = bgdivisi.c_kodediv AND
              bggroup1.c_kodegrp0 = bggroup0.c_kodegrp0 AND
              bggroup1.c_kodegrp1 LIKE '%') AS nilai
FROM bgdivisi JOIN bggroup0 ON 1 = 1
JOIN bgdepartemen on bgdivisi.c_kodedept = bgdepartemen.c_kodedept
WHERE bgdivisi.c_kodediv LIKE '%' AND
     bgdepartemen.c_kodedept LIKE '%' AND
     bggroup0.c_kodegrp0 LIKE '%'
```

And another like this:

```
SELECT bgdepartemen.c_kodedept AS c_kodedept,
       bgdepartemen.vc_namadept AS vc_namadept,
       bgdivisi.c_kodediv AS c_kodediv,
       bgdivisi.vc_namadiv AS vc_namadiv,
       bggroup0.c_kodegrp0 AS c_kodegrp0,
       bggroup0.vc_namagrp0 AS vc_namagrp0,
       (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(bgrealisasi0.n_nilai))
        FROM (bgrealisasi0 JOIN bggroup1 ON bgrealisasi0.c_kodegrp1 = bggroup1.c_kodegrp1)
        WHERE bgrealisasi0.n_tahun = 2016 AND
        bgrealisasi0.n_bulan >= 2 AND
        bgrealisasi0.n_bulan <= 3 AND
        bgrealisasi0.c_kodediv = bgdivisi.c_kodediv AND
        bggroup1.c_kodegrp0=bggroup0.c_kodegrp0 AND
        bggroup1.c_kodegrp1 LIKE '%') AS nilai
FROM bgdivisi JOIN bggroup0 ON 1 = 1
JOIN bgdepartemen on bgdivisi.c_kodedept = bgdepartemen.c_kodedept
WHERE bgdivisi.c_kodediv LIKE '%' AND
      bgdepartemen.c_kodedept LIKE '%' AND
      bggroup0.c_kodegrp0 LIKE '%'
```

I want to select from those tables, with condition

```
 WHERE a.c_kodedept = b.c_kodedept AND
            a.c_kodediv = b.c_kodediv AND
            a.c_kodegrp0 = b.c_kodegrp0 AND
            (a.nilai is not null or b.nilai is not null)
```

But I also want to change the null record which appears with 0, I've tried `COALESCE` but it still doesn't give me the right result.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What is "a"?  What is "b"?  You seem to understand how to avoid `NULL` values.

Comment: try ISNULL(columnName, 0)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In general you would first set `NULL` values to `0` and then `SUM` them:

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(bgrealisasi0.n_nilai, 0)) ...
```

Otherwise your queries have a few deficiencies such as `field LIKE '%'` which is a really inefficient way of writing `field IS NOT NULL`. The use of a scalar sub-query makes the overall query really difficult to read and the joins can probably be optimized if rewritten as a sub-query instead.

Answer (score 17):

You should use

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(bgbudget0.n_nilai), 0) 
FROM .....
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(bgrealisasi0.n_nilai), 0) 
FROM ....
```

Answer (score 5):

In Postgres starting with version 9.4, `SUM` ignores nulls:

> sum of expression across all non-null input values

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-aggregate.html

Note that if ALL inputs are null, the aggregate value will be null.

Answer (score -5):

Not really understand whats your question but if you want change null value to 0 can refer query below:

```
ISNULL(SUM(column_name), 0)
```

Comment: `ISNULL` is not a Postgresql function